# (Android Studio Develop) : Return Pin's latitude and longitude from Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to get user's location(latitude and longitude) when they dropped pin on the map that I made. How to convert the information to string, I want to show these information on textview, Thanks a lot.

Comment: you want to show address of that location or latitude and longitude of that location?

Comment: latitude and longitude of that location.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location using pin object like below

```
Double latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
Double longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;
```

here marker is your pin object.
after that you can show this latitude and longitude in your textview like this.

```
 textView.setText(""+latitude);
 textView.setText(""+longitude);
```

Comment: The Code is too long. Could I send it as e mail?

Comment: I recived the mail. Thanks a lot.